# Where to find AOT flag in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-aot

1) Where in Angular.io website documentation i can find that  AOT is already enabled by default in Angular 6?

2)I have my cli based application of Angular 6. In which file can i find this flag so i can enable or disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the command line, you can follow what @Sajeetharan stated in his answer. However, take note that all flags are to be used with **2 hyphens**, not **1 hyphen** as what Sajeetharan did:

```bash
ng build --prod --aot=false
```

For the Angular workspace file (aka `angular.json`), this can be found in the `configurations` object:

```json
{
  "projects": {
    "my-project": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "aot": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**[AOT](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)** is one of the compilation method which compiles app in prod mode,

The flag **`--prod`** does the **`AOT compilation`** by default.you can disable it by setting **`-aot`** to be **`false`**

```
ng build -prod -aot=false.
```

This will disable the aot compiler.